# R - How do I lag/lead multiple columns in a data.table by multiple periods most efficiently

Tags: r, datatable

Having a large data.table that stores one date column (monthly) and then a bunch of different variables of interest measured at the respective dates for various subjects/IDs. Now I want to add for a subset of those variables (only some columns) newly computed columns that lead **AND** lag those columns by **multiple** periods all at once. Is that doable?
See below for the illustration of some example data that represents the high-level structure of my table and for what I tried so far

```
Date        ID   Var_A   Var_B   Var_C
2000-01-31  1    100     500     1000
2000-02-28  1    200     600     1100
2000-03-31  1    300     700     1200
2000-04-30  1    400     800     1300 
2000-01-31  2    100     500     1000
2000-02-28  2    200     600     1100
2000-03-31  2    300     700     1200
2000-04-30  2    400     800     1300

dt[, `:=`(Var_A_Lag_1 = shift(Var_A_Lag_1, 1),
          Var_A_Lead_1 = shift(Var_A_Lead_1, 1, type = 'lead'),
          Var_A_Lag_2 = shift(Var_A_Lag_1, 2),
          Var_A_Lead_2 = shift(Var_A_Lead_1, 2, type = 'lead'),
          Var_B_Lag_1 = shift(Var_B_Lag_1, 1),
          Var_B_Lead_1 = shift(Var_B_Lead_1, 1, type = 'lead'),
          Var_B_Lag_2 = shift(Var_B_Lag_1, 2),
          Var_B_Lead_2 = shift(Var_B_Lead_1, 2, type = 'lead')),
   by = ID]
```

But that cannot be efficient can it? I tried sth that I thought was very intuitive and would work but no luck.

```
cols_to_edit <- which(sapply(dt, is.numeric))
cols_to_edit <- colnames(dt[, cols_to_edit, with = FALSE])

# col names od shifted variables
col_names_lag_1 <- paste(cols_to_edit, "lag_1", sep = "_")
col_names_lag_2 <- paste(cols_to_edit, "lag_2", sep = "_")
col_names_lead_1 <- paste(cols_to_edit, "lead_1", sep = "_")
col_names_lead_2 <- paste(cols_to_edit, "lead_2", sep = "_")

# colnames for differences 
col_names_lag_1_d <- paste("d", cols_to_edit, "lag_1", sep = "_")
col_names_lag_2_d <- paste("d", cols_to_edit, "lag_2", sep = "_")
col_names_lead_1_d <- paste("d", cols_to_edit, "lead_1", sep = "_")
col_names_lead_2_d <- paste("d", cols_to_edit, "lead_2", sep = "_")

# Execute the shift command
dt_2[, (col_names_lag_1) := shift(cols_to_edit, 1), by = ID] 
# would have repeated for all new columns as defined above but it is not working.
```

I basically want all numeric variables in this table shifted, say by 1 and 2 respectively in either directio. The newly computed values should then be assigned to the columns named by the name vector declared above. Didn't find any other question that was similiar to my case here. Do you have any idea or know a best practice for doing this?

The context:
The variables are selected metrics as input for a regression model requiring the input to be available in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this in a nice little `for` loop:

```
cols <- grep("Var", names(dt), value = TRUE)
for ( i in 1:2 ) { # update for the number of shifts
  
  lag_names <- paste(cols, "Lag", i, sep = "_")
  dt[, (lag_names) := lapply(.SD, shift, i, type = "lag"), .SDcols = cols]
  
  lead_names <- paste(cols, "Lead", i, sep = "_")
  dt[, (lead_names) := lapply(.SD, shift, i, type = "lead"), .SDcols = cols]
  
}
```

Comment: This looks very intuitive to me. And your code looks way more elegant than mine ... Will try it out later today as soon as I get the chance! 

I never thought about this. Initially I was wondering if you could do looped ```:=``` assignment using ```set()``` but this only works row-wise. Maybe I could 'enhance' this proposed solution by looping outside by the number of shifts required and inside using just ```1:nrow(dt)``` by looping through all rows and thereby enabling ```set()```. I'll try that and if it does work, I'll benchmark both and choose the better performing one.

Comment: As you had this great idea already, do you have a clue how one were to implement differences columns to the original period of all shifted columns, in the sense of ```diff(var_xy_lag_n) = (var_xy - var_xy_lag_n)``` and correspondingly ```diff(var_xy_lead_n) = (var_xy_lead_n - var_xy)```? Could I just embed them after the corresponding lines that add the necessary columns by reference in the for loop?

Comment: I marked it as helpful for now. Like I said initially, I will try your proposed code asap and then mark it as solved/accepted if things work out! 
Thumbs up Paul for your wonderful suggestion!!

Comment: I don't use {data.table} every day, so it will take some working out. I probably won't be able to get to this today; it might be worthwhile for you to ask another question. (post the link here, I'll have a look if I get the chance before someone else sees it.)

Comment: All right! Thanks pal for bringing me this far!

As for the way I am trying to frame this is by defining a new column name and then after computing the corresponding cols, I'll just use the ````diff()``` function.

Comment: I did get a chance, what if you replace the `lapply()` with: `lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x, i, type = "lag"))` for both lag and lead? I don't now how it will scale, but it works fast for 8 rows of data :-)

Comment: To clarify, one would have to write one line per shift direction right. For lag it would be
```lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x, i, type = "lag"))``` and for lead it would be ```lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, i, type = "lead") - x)```

Comment: By the way, I must admit, that looks pretty neat. I thought about it in the meantime and would have probably started with trying ```lag_names_diff <- paste(cols, "Lag", i, "d", sep = "_")``` and ```dt[, (lag_names_diff) := lapply(.SD, diff, cols, lag_names), .SDcols = cols]``` and correspondingly for lead ```lead_names_diff <- paste(cols, "Lead", i, "d", sep = "_")``` and ```dt[, (lag_names_diff) := lapply(.SD, diff, lead_names, cols), .SDcols = cols]```. Don't even know if that code would run at all....

Comment: Yes, one for both lag and lead.

Comment: Great! Awesome mate! I did change the diff order though for the one shift type. For lead it would be the diff of the ```'lead' variable to the original one``` and for lag it would be the other way round, like ```original variable - 'lagged' variable```

Comment: I tried everything Paul to make the loop work but unfortunately after 1.5 days of experimenting with it, I am still not any closer to a working solution. The error data.table outputs as a result of executing the loop is the following:

Comment: ```Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.``` It works but not within a loop...